# Attribute already defined with incompatible format

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting this error in my project, and I cannot for the life of me find where my `navigationMode` is getting defined twice.

`Error:(707) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.`

The source of the error is this file:
`/Users/temp/code/MyCoolProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml`

How is this file generated? I didn't write it.

Here it is defined in my:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="navigationMode">
        <enum name="listMode" value="1" />
        <enum name="normal" value="0" />
        <enum name="tabMode" value="2" />
    </attr>
</resources>
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: did u find a solution for that ?

Answer (score -3):

Check your operations with action bar.